# Tensorflow: Alternative to DenseFeatures input layer for ability of porting to tfjs

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras

I have a regression network that takes in a set of binary input vectors of features and yields a linear output. However, I have used the DenseFeatures functionality for my input layer as shown below

```
feature_columns = []
for header in ['FEATURE1', 'FEATURE2', 'FEATURE3', 'FEATURE4', 'FEATURE5']:
    feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(header))


feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
```

And the full model being

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    feature_layer,
    layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    layers.Dense(1), activation='relu'
  ])
```

However, when I export this model from my python environment (running the 2.0 alpha version of Tensorflow) and try to import it into my node.js app by the following:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
tf.loadLayersModel('/PATH_TO_FILE/model.json');
```

I get the following error:

```
Unknown layer: DenseFeatures
```

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that the DenseFeatures functionality has yet to be ported to the javascript version of Tensorflow?

As such, what would be a suitable replacement for the input layer, to still get the same functionality? The data is comprised of 5 binary features (either the artifact under study have the feature or not), and the output is a number, for example, the price of the artifact. Thus a suitable datapoint would be.

(1,0,1,0,0), (100)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.loadGraphModel` instead of `tf.loadLayersModel`. That way you can use DenseFeatures inside `tfjs`.

Use the converter to create a graph model:

```
model.save(temp_path, overwrite=True)
tfjs.converters.convert_tf_saved_model(temp_path, out_path)
```

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2443) is an issue tracking support for `DenseFeatures` and `loadLayersModel`.